# Jquery slideToggle causing white space with inline-block divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a list of cities displaying inline.

```
<div class="accordion-container">
    <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">Rome</a>
    <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>..</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When selecting the header of a city, using the slideToggle, I display some info on that city.

```
accordionContent.slideToggle(250);
```

But it also slide's down the city header next to it, causing a big white space area.  Is there a way to only slide the divs below the selected div?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cone06kr/1/)

Comment: Why dont you have separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the vertical alignment to `top` in your CSS to keep the other header where it is:

```
.accordion-container {
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/cone06kr/4/)

**OR**

You could set the content to `position: absolute` so it breaks out of it's container:

```
.accordion-content {
    background: #FFF;
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/cone06kr/6/)

Comment: I like that vertical-align: top;  keeps the headers at the top of the respective 'rows'.  But it still causes the whitespace issue in the content.  is the only way to get what I am looking for to use a table?

Comment: No the only way to not create whitespace is to use example 2, anything else (in the flow of the document) is going to push those headers below down. @AarronH

Comment: how would you change the flow of the document to achieve the effect I am looking for? @jmore009

Comment: @AarronH by using `position: absolute` which removes the element from the flow of the document. You see in example 2 how the content just slides down over the other headers? It doesnt push them down because it's not being recognized as an element within the flow of the document.

Comment: I set this one as the answer as I decided to go the position: absolute route.  Thanks @jmore009

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to have to have two separate columns for this, then:

```
.accordion-container {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
}
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cone06kr/10/

You'll need to shift the content about to get it back in your original order.

If you're generating this content you'll need two loops, one for odds the other for evens.

Comment: I really like this way because it looks great for a static sized site.  but if i need it to be responsive, as in the number of columns can change based on screen size, could I achieve this?

Comment: Hmmm, that is tricky. You might be able to use script to detect the number of columns resulting from your media queries, and then redeal out the cards between them, so to speak. This library http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ looks like it might be handy for reacting to the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how yo want it to look. But a simple fix is adding `vertical-align: top;`

```
.accordion-container {
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```